# gradle: no repositories are defined

Tags: java, gradle, grails

I'm new to gradle.
I fetched an old gradle based project on a new computer, and when I tried to build it, it failed with "`Could not determine java version from '11'.`". I updated the gradle version to 5.0, using `gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 5.0` (from a recent system wide gradle installation). And now any gradle command fails with:

```
> Configure project :
Cannot resolve reloading agent JAR: Failed to resolve imported Maven boms: Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.5.12.RELEASE because no repositories are defined.
```

In my build.gradle, a repository is defined, so I don't understand the error:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
                jcenter()
                mavenLocal()
                maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        }
        dependencies {
               ...
        }
}

repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}
```

Comment: I assume, this is a grails 3 project?  Gradle 5 is brand new and the default for Grails 3 projects is still Gradle 3 (last time i checked).  So you might have to go the other way around: downgrade your Java to 8 (e.g. use SDK-MAN or docker etc). Grails brings additional stuff into Gradle and this is old stuff - so i have my strongest doubts, that you will have a pleasant journey with updating.

Comment: Gradle 4.9 still works fine under Grails 3.3.6 with some warnings.

Comment: Using gradle 4.9 and grails 3.3.6, I get this stacktrace error when compiling `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache`

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 5 is new release. It needs more time to be compatible to Grails version. It would be better to downgrade your gradle along with jdk version. Have a look on it https://adtmag.com/blogs/watersworks/2018/11/gradle-5-0.aspx